# What does high-pressure ice look like?

Tags: states-of-matter, ice

Suppose one had a pressure chamber of extreme strength, strength enough to hold 100s of MPa worth of pressure inside. So you put some ice cubes in the chamber (regular ice), keeping the temperature low enough it doesn't melt (so you can see the transition I'm curious about). Then you increase the pressure (if there is some kind of gas which can still be a gas or at least supercritical under these conditions so you can keep pressurizing the chamber) up to the point (keeping the temperature in range) where the ice transforms form normal ice into one of the higher-pressure forms of ice. If there were a way to see inside with visible light, would you notice a change in the appearance of the ice? If so, what? For example, consider the diagram here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_diagram#mediaviewer/File:Phase_diagram_of_water.svg

It looks that if ice were kept at a temperature of, say, 245 K, and the pressure were raised from normal atmospheric to, say, 220 MPa (though the transition looks to be somewhat lower than that), it will change to "Ice III" (which looks to be one of the lowest-pressure forms of the high-pressure ices). What would that look like? Especially, what would the ice cubes do as you cross the phase boundary, visibly speaking? Would it change color? Would they crack and break from a density change? What would the other forms of high-pressure ice look like, anyways, were it possible to photograph them?

Comment: Also see: [What do different forms of ice look like?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20214/what-do-different-forms-of-ice-look-like/20229#20229)

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't using the right search terms, apparently. Feel free to close this one down if you want.